# How to display row number next to each row on contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a contenteditable div and I want the site to count each row of text the user has in the div similar to many coding IDEs. (Example image below to show what I mean:)
[image]

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: There are many ways to do this. What have you tried? An `<ol>` with `<li>` Elements in it? A table? `display:flex;`? `display:grid;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with two container elements and a little bit of scripting:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#edit').css('min-height', $('#edit').height());
  $('#edit').html('');
  var currentHeight = $('#edit').height();
  var lineHeight = currentHeight;
  $('#edit').keyup(function(){
    if($(this).height()!=currentHeight){
      currentHeight = $(this).height();
      var lines = currentHeight/lineHeight;
      $('#nums').html('')
      for (i = 1; i < lines+1; i++) {
        $('#nums').append('<span>'+i+'</span>')
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#container{
  border: 2px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
}

#nums{
  width: 25px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

#nums span{
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

#edit{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

#editwrapper{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="nums">
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div id="editwrapper">
    <div id="edit" contenteditable="true">
      filler
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly on the stackoverflow run code snippet, yet for whatever reason I can't seem to get it to work in my project. If I try to add more rows to the contenteditable, more rows appear yet only the first rows number is actually visible.

Comment: @Koto Try to reproduce what is happening

Comment: Check my edit above in the original post to see what I have so far.

Comment: ok nevermind I'm just a moron and incorrectly set up my script tags. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

That's not so simple, actually. If a user typed in your div and the text wrapped, JavaScript doesn't know that it wrapped; there's no row to count!

This solution is super specific, and I'll leave showing the line numbers to you:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="myDiv" style="width:300px;font-family:monospace" onchange="myHandler()"></div>

<script>
const limit = 40 // number of monospace chars to fill a row
let count = 0
function myHandler (e) {
  let lines = Math.ceil(e.target.value.length / limit)
  if (lines !== count) {
    showlines(lines) // your function to display the line #s
    count = lines
  }
}
</script>
```

Takeaway: your div should be a fixed width and you should count how many monospace chars fit within that width. Then display those lines.

Comment: You can just use height compared to a reference, see my answer